# Write Unicode character with integer value to text file in Python 2

Tags: python, unicode

1. In Python 2, I want to write a Unicode character which integer value is `k` to text file.

How should I do that?

(For instance, with ASCII, if I want to write the character with value 65, in text file it should appeared as 'A').

2. Afterwards, how should I read the file back to integer value?
3. The last question, how many Unicode characters are there in total? (as I know, there are more than one Unicode alphabets, such as UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.)

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is one unicode (about 120, 000 chars). It is ENCODED in may ways ljke utf-8, utf-16 for storage. To turn an int into a unicode char use `unichr( k )`.

Comment: limit your questions to one issue per question (so that they could be more applicable to others).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't write Unicode code points to text files.  They must be encoded.  UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are encodings that support the full range of Unicode code points.  `unichr()` is the function to turn an integer into a Unicode codepoint.  Note that Python 2 will default to an encoding that depends on your operating system if you don't specify one, but it won't be able to write *all* Unicode characters unless that default is one of the UTF encodings.

Create a Unicode character:

```
k = 65
u = unichr(k)
```

Write it to a file encoded in UTF-8:

```
import io
with io.open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(u)
```

2. `ord()` will convert a character back to an integer.

Example (make sure to open with the same encoding as written):

```
import io
with io.open('output.txt',encoding='utf8') as f:
u = f.read()
k = ord(u)
```

3. Unicode code points range from U+0000 to U+10FFFF.  Not all code points are defined, but there are 1,114,112 possible values in that range.